# Is the require function part of the AMD spec?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've been working with AMD modules and RequireJS quite a bit lately and I'm trying to figure out exactly what the AMD spec is.  So far the only thing I've been able to find is the amdjs GitHub page at https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD.

This page only shows the `define( id, dependencies, factory)` function as part of the official spec.  Require has another function called `require( dependencies, callback )` and I'm not sure if its part of the official spec or if its just a conviennece function provided by the RequireJS library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the page you linked, under the heading Global Variables:

> This specification reserves the global variable "define" for use in
>   implementing this specification, the package metadata asynchronous
>   definition API and is reserved for other future CommonJS APIs. Module
>   loaders SHOULD not add additional methods or properties to this
>   function.
>
> **This specification reserves the global variable "require" for use by
>   module loaders. Module loaders are free to use this global variable as
>   they see fit. They may use the variable and add any properties or
>   functions to it as desired for module loader specific functionality.
>   They can also choose not to use "require" as well.**

[Curl](https://github.com/cujojs/curl) is an example of an AMD loader that doesn't use `require`.

In addition [there is a page that details the `require` API](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/require) for loaders that support it.